# special character replacement not working

Tags: php, special-characters, str-replace

I have written this method to replace special characters:

```
function replace_sonder($string)
    {
        $string2 = str_replace("ä", "&auml;", $string);
        $string2 = str_replace("%E4", "&auml;", $string2);
        $string2 = str_replace("ö", "&ouml;", $string2);
        $string2 = str_replace("%F6", "&ouml;", $string2);
        $string2 = str_replace("ü", "&uuml;", $string2);
        $string2 = str_replace("%FC", "&uuml;", $string2);
        $string2 = str_replace("Ä", "&Auml;", $string2);
        $string2 = str_replace("%C4", "&Auml;", $string2);
        $string2 = str_replace("Ö", "&Ouml;", $string2);
        $string2 = str_replace("%D6", "&Ouml;", $string2);
        $string2 = str_replace("Ü", "&Uuml;", $string2);
        $string2 = str_replace("%DC", "&Uuml;", $string2);
        $string2 = str_replace("ß", "&szlig;", $string2);
        $string2 = str_replace("%DF", "&szlig;", $string2);
        return $string2;
    }
```

it always returns the same string that I pass in. Where am I missing something or is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: have you set up to file-encoding type UTF-8 or UTF-16?

Comment: What is your input string?

Comment: Your function in the short way: `function replace_sonder($string) {
  return $string = htmlentities(rawurldecode($string)); 
 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace("/ä/", "&auml;", $string);
...
```

but better way is:

```
$string = htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: - 1 preg replace does not accomplish the goals of the OP

Comment: @Paedow your function have two different "functions". First of all it converts UNICODE to HTML entities, as I reflect above. The second is the conversion URL parameters from `$_REQUEST['unicode_param']` to HTML entities. I believe, to mix this two functionalities entire one custom function is wrong practice.

Answer (score 0):

Check the output you're comparing is not to an HTML page as it will convert the characters back again.